# How to measure decoding performance when using MSE or WebRTC?

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, h.264, media-source

For the test I'm thinking of using WebSocket to push stream to the client, video encoded as Fragmented MP4. Then the client decodes the stream ASAP using (`MediaSource`)MSE and (`MediaStream`)WebRTC along with HTML5 `<video>` tag. This is just a test, for real use case I'm targeting real-time live stream.

Is there a way for me to measure the frame by frame decoding time? i.e. how long takes the decoder to decode a frame and renderer renders a frame? Alternatively how i can get the real-time FPS for that?

Comment: What is it you want to measure exactly? What for? The time taken to decode one frame means nothing really. Videos aren't decoded frame by frame, in most cases they're not even painted frame by frame.

Comment: https://github.com/muaz-khan/getStats might help

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest you can get is by watching the `webkitDroppedFrameCount` and `webkitDecodedFrameCount` properties of the HTMLVideoElement over time.  (Note, this only works in Chrome.)  This isn't really going to give you the time for decoded frames, but will help you measure related performance.

The time to decode one frame isn't really all that useful to you.  It's going to be the same, regardless of where the data came from.  It's also going to be different from frame to frame.  What matters is that the decoder can keep up with the playback rate.

I should also point out that there's no reason to use web sockets if you're only sending data one direction.  If you're just streaming video data to a client, use regular HTTP!  You can stream the response with the Fetch API and skip the overhead of web sockets entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can check some useful matrix several ways during WebRTC using.

### webrtc-internals(Chrome only)

If you try to WebRTC, you can check WebRTC internal.

After create peerConnection object, in the Address Bar on Chrome, try to type following.

> chrome://webrtc-internals

- [WebRTC Internals Document](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-internals-documentation/)
- [WebRTC Externals browser extension for other browser](https://github.com/fippo/webrtc-externals)

Then you can check some useful matrix.

#### FPS

on `Stats graphs for ssrc_****_recv (ssrc) (video)`

You can check frame rate with like `googFrameRateDecoded` `googFrameRateOutput` `googFrameRateReceived` value.

#### Delay

on `Stats graphs for ssrc_****_recv (ssrc) (video)`

You can check delay with like `googTargetDelayMs` `googRenderDelayMs` `googJitterBufferMs`.

More about these matrix to real practice, check this out.

https://flashphoner.com/oh-webcam-online-broadcasting-latency-thou-art-a-heartless-bitch/

### WebRTC Standard Stats

Also you can access stats by standard way from peerConnection object.

- [WebRTC Standard Stats](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#sec.stats-model)
- [WebRTC Stats API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/)

  - https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcreceivedrtpstreamstats

    - RTCReceivedRtpStreamStats - jitter
  - https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcvideoreceiverstats

    - RTCVideoReceiverStats - jitterBufferDelayed